# How can I compress a folder and email the compressed file in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to compress a folder and all its sub-folders/files, and email the zip file as an attachment. What would be the best way to achieve this with Python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/zipfile.html) module to compress the file using the zip standard, the [email](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.html) module to create the email with the attachment, and the [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/smtplib.html) module to send it - all using only the standard library.

## Python - Batteries Included

If you don't feel like programming and would rather ask a question on stackoverflow.org instead, or (as suggested in the comments) left off the `homework` tag, well, here it is:

```
import smtplib
import zipfile
import tempfile
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart    

def send_file_zipped(the_file, recipients, sender='you@you.com'):
    zf = tempfile.TemporaryFile(prefix='mail', suffix='.zip')
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')
    zip.write(the_file)
    zip.close()
    zf.seek(0)

    # Create the message
    themsg = MIMEMultipart()
    themsg['Subject'] = 'File %s' % the_file
    themsg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    themsg['From'] = sender
    themsg.preamble = 'I am not using a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
    msg = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
    msg.set_payload(zf.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(msg)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 
                   filename=the_file + '.zip')
    themsg.attach(msg)
    themsg = themsg.as_string()

    # send the message
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
    smtp.connect()
    smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients, themsg)
    smtp.close()

    """
    # alternative to the above 4 lines if you're using gmail
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.login("username", "password")
    server.sendmail(sender,recipients,themsg)
    server.quit()
    """
```

With this function, you can just do:

```
send_file_zipped('result.txt', ['me@me.org'])
```

You're welcome.

Comment: That's one hell of an answer.

Comment: Since you got into the trouble of answering, edit your answer to add a directory tree in the zip, not just a single file.

Comment: Thank you very much. It wasn't a homework. I'm a php programmer who's trying to switch to Python. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: to get your sample working I had to remove the line smtp.connect() as it was giving me socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: @Bryce Thomas: That's probably because you don't have a SMTP server running on your machine. In mine it works fine.

Comment: Man, I had it all but forgot about `.seek(0)` and my files were always corrupted... Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [zipfile](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-zipfile.html) for compressing a folder and it's subfolders.

Look at [smtplib](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-smtplib.html) for an email client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zipfile](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-zipfile.html) that ships with python, and [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2038) you can find an example of sending an email with attachments with the standard smtplib